# problem with singleton's methods in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios4, methods, singleton

I'm doing singleton and A cannot use methods on it... the type for arguments is not right apparently... and there are lots of mistakes (errors)...

Errors are in comment (in the code)

In a foreign Class :

```
[ [MySingleton sharedMySingleton] setAuth:@"test"]; //incompatible type for argument 1 of setAuth
NSLog([ [MySingleton sharedMySingleton] getAuth]); //Incompatible type for argument 1 os NSLOG
```

In my singleton's Classes :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface MySingleton : NSObject {

    NSString *myToken;

}

+(MySingleton*)sharedMySingleton;

-(void)setAuth:(NSString) token;
-(NSString)getAuth;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myToken;

@end
```

... and ...

```
    #import "MySingleton.h"

@implementation MySingleton

static MySingleton* _sharedMySingleton = nil;
@synthesize myToken;

+(MySingleton*)sharedMySingleton
{
    @synchronized([MySingleton class])
    {
        if (!_sharedMySingleton)
            [[self alloc] init];

        return _sharedMySingleton;
    }

    return nil;
}

+(id)alloc
{
    @synchronized([MySingleton class])
    {
        NSAssert(_sharedMySingleton == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton.");
        _sharedMySingleton = [super alloc];
        return _sharedMySingleton;
    }

    return nil;
}

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        // initialize stuff here
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)setAuth:(NSString) token { // Can not use as abject as parameter to a method
    myToken=token;// incomatible types in assignment
}

-(NSString)getAuth { // can not use an object as parameter to a method
    return myToken;// incomatible types in return
} // control reaches end of non-void function


@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-(void)setAuth:(NSString) token;
-(NSString)getAuth;
```

should be

```
-(void)setAuth:(NSString*) token;
//                      ^ note a pointer is needed
-(NSString*)getAuth;
//        ^ note a pointer is needed
```

---

Also, your alloc is crazy.  You actually invoke `[super alloc]` which will give you an object of the wrong type.  Check out [how to implement singleton in objective-c for iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518512/how-to-implement-singleton-in-objective-c-for-iphone) for better ways to do singletons.

Comment: finally an answer that explains a bit, and not just saying "a `*` is missing`

Answer (score 1):

Your header file is missing the `*` for the `NSString` type. For example, it should be :

```
-(void)setAuth:(NSString *) token;
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `NSString`  with `NSString*` everywhere.